# UITableview with dynamic height cells & filling footer view

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to make a UITableview with a footer view that fills the remaining empty space of the UITableview. However, the catch is that the cells have varying heights.

I am aware that, if the cells were all a static height, I could simply count how many cells there are and multiply that by the static height. Unfortunately, that won't work in this case.

Current solution:

Works for static height cells.

Does not work for dynamic height cells.

```
    private func adjustFooterHeight() {
        if data.count == 0 {
            footerView.frame.size.height = tableView.bounds.height
        }
        else {
            //I use data.count instead of (data.count - 1) as I have the extra hidden cell, as pictured in image 2.
            let bottomFrame = tableView.rectForRow(at: IndexPath(row: data.count, section: 0))
            let height = tableView.bounds.height - (bottomFrame.origin.y + bottomFrame.height - rowHeight)
            footerView.frame.size.height = height < 0 ? 0 : height
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Diagram of Intentions:

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to fill it with a very customized view or do you just want the rest of the TableView to be a solid color? White for example?

Comment: I don't particularly want the view to have a lot of content, but it needs to make the table view's content reach to the bottom of the view controllers frame. Once the table view has enough cells to go past the size of the screen, it's fine, I don't need it, but until then I do. I am using this footer view to make the table view scrollable, as I have my first cell of the table view hidden above the view controller. It is sort of like a hidden pull down action. I'll update my post with a picture or two.

Comment: Pictures for context would be great :)

Comment: Did you implement cell heights using `heightForRowAtIndexPath`? If so, it's not entirely dynamic and you can define footer heights in `heightForFooterInSection` without reloading data.

Comment: I am returning UITableViewAutomaticDimensions for the heightForRowAtIndexPath, as the content of each cell can vary based on the amount of text it has to fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out...

Here is the solution.

```
    private func adjustFooterHeight() {

        //Get content height & calculate new footer height.
        let cells = self.tableView.visibleCells
        var height: CGFloat = 0
        for i in 0..<cells.count {
             height += cells[i].frame.height
        }
        height = self.tableView.bounds.height - ceil(height)

        //If the footer's new height is negative, we make it 0, since we don't need footer anymore.
        height = height > 0 ? height : 0

        //Create the footer
        let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: height))
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to work but when do you call this func (adjustFooterHeight()) in the life cycle ?

In advance thank you.

Kind Regards,

Comment: You should call this func right after call function tableView.reloadData().